# Read video frame directly in grayscale with Python OpenCV cv2.VideoCapture()

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video, computer-vision

I am working with OpenCV. I have a video file, and I want to read it in grayscale, instead of converting every frame in grayscale. i.e

```py
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(VIDEO_PATH)

results = {}
curr_frame = 0
start = time.time()
while(cap.isOpened()):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        curr_frame+=1
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

I do not want to do this, instead I want to read it directly in grayscale as we do in images i.e

```
im_gray = cv2.imread('grayscale_image.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

Now upon inspecting the documentation, I found that the read function "The method/function combines VideoCapture::grab() and VideoCapture::retrieve() in one call."
And inside retrieve, we can pass a flag value. Is it possible to combine it with read and read it in gray scale instead of converting it explicitly?

I tried doing

```
ret, frame = cap.read(flag=0)
```

But it is not a valid keyword argument.

```
error: OpenCV(4.5.5) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'read'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - 'flag' is an invalid keyword argument for VideoCapture.read()
>  - 'flag' is an invalid keyword argument for VideoCapture.read()
```

But I can pass in any random number in `cap.read()` and it works.

```
cap.read(-4)
```

I was looking for source code in Python, but can not found any source code in Python for this function on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`VideoCaptureModes` documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#gad0f42b32af0d89d2cee80dae0ea62b3d), there are four possible modes:

```
cv2.CAP_MODE_BGR - BGR24 (default)
cv2.CAP_MODE_RGB - RGB24
cv2.CAP_MODE_GRAY - Y8
cv2.CAP_MODE_YUYV - YUYV
```

Also note:

> Currently, these are supported through the libv4l backend only.

So to read video frames directly as grayscale using `cv2.VideoCapture()`, you have to set the mode to grayscale with `cv2.CAP_MODE_GRAY` like this:

```
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
possible = capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_MODE, cv2.CAP_MODE_GRAY)
print(possible)

# IMPORTANT: Check this value to see if it's supported by your system
```

You have to check the returned `bool` value to see if it's possible since it may or may not be supported by your OS, camera, hardware, or backend. If the returned value is `False` or you get an error like this

> AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'CAP_MODE_GRAY'

then unfortunately it's not possible for your system, the best thing you can do is convert to grayscale with `cv2.cvtColor` after retrieving the frame.

---

Here's a working example to read frames directly as grayscale from a webcam

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import cv2, time

def capture_frames():
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    possible = capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_MODE, cv2.CAP_MODE_GRAY)
    print(possible)

    # FPS = 1/X, X = desired FPS
    FPS = 1/120
    FPS_MS = int(FPS * 1000)

    while True:
        # Ensure camera is connected
        if capture.isOpened():
            (status, frame) = capture.read()
            
            # Ensure valid frame
            if status:
                cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
            else:
                break
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
            time.sleep(FPS)

    capture.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Starting video stream')
    capture_process = mp.Process(target=capture_frames, args=())
    capture_process.start()
```

Comment: Seems like I do not have this `AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'CAP_MODE_GRAY'`
Also you are passing 0 to video capture, if one has to pass the file path, should the file path first argument?

Comment: I dont even have the default one `AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'CAP_MODE_BGR'`

Comment: I'm passing `0` to use my webcam, you can use whatever link. See [here for the VideoCapture doc](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a85b55cf6a4a50451367ba96b65218ba1). If you're getting any error at all I believe it's not supported on your system. Can you read frames normally in BGR form?

Comment: Yeah those 4 modes are `"Currently, these are supported through the libv4l backend only."` so if you get an error at all then directly reading grayscale is impossible. Your only option is to convert it to gray using `cvtColor` after frames are read or configure your camera to output grayscale

Comment: Yes I can read via webcam using 0. or via file if I pass the file path. But I can not use the capture.set argument.
Thanks for your help.